# Build .jar with Gradle, execute the .jar local throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Creating the .jar via Gradle works fine. When running the .jar, an exception is thrown.
(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

I have a locals .jar in my project which I included via Gradle Dependecies. When compiling, the classes can be resolved from the locals .jar. The library is in both the CompileClassPath and the RuntimeClassPath.

Are the external .jar (even if they are Local) included in the new build or does a new classpath variable need to be created in the system?

The program should eventually be run on an Ubuntu machine.

Gradle Dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

[RuntimeClassPath & CompileClassPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdvIo.png)

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at/fhv/teamE/sharedLib/RmiCustomerDatabaseInterface
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at at.fhv.teamE.communication.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.fhv.teamE.sharedLib.RmiCustomerDatabaseInterface
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Post the full error please.

Comment: Now you can see the full stacktrace.